# Test multiple Spice Models in different testbenches

Tags: cadence

I am new to cadence, and I am trying to figure out if there is an easy way to setup i.e. 5 testbenches where I can specify a list of spice models to run through the 5 testbenches?

I am open to any solution, currently looking at both `ADE XL`, `SKILL` and `OCEAN` trying to find out what is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Cadence has a Skill IDE here: CIW > Tools > Skill IDE. Look into the documentation for Skill. Once you find the command for simulating, you can use a for loop:

```
foreach(cellId ddGetObj(library_name)->cells

    simulator('spectre)
    design(library_name cellId->name "schematic")
    ;Simulate Here

)
```

You will have to modify this loop for your purposes it is just an example.
Hope this gets you started.